# Passing html textbox value as a parameter to controllers method in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass the `Html.Textbox` value to a controller from anchor tag, so that I can search the value passed to a controller. Please tell me how can I achieve this.

```
<a  href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {  })">@p</a>

public ActionResult Index(string String)
        {


        }

@Html.TextBox("String")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use jquery

```
@Html.TextBox("String", null, new { @class="txtString" })
<a  href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {  })" class="linkAction">@p</a>
```

then in your script

```
$('.txtString').on('blur', function(){
    $('.linkAction').attr('src', '@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { text = "----" })'.replace("----", $('.txtString').val()));
});
```

Comment: it shows { class = txtString } in a text box. Is there any mistake in syntax.

Comment: sorry put the class into the object values instead of the html values.  added a null for the object values so it should render correctly now

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use jQuery. If you're doing a `HttpPost`, you just need the "name" of the textbox.

On your page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.TextBox(string.Empty, new { name = "textbox" })

    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string textbox) {
    // The name of the string parameter must match the name given to the TextBox element on the page.
}
```

Comment: Can i pass the name with the help of anchor tag as i pass page number as below : <a class="name" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { page = p })">@p</a>

Comment: For that, you'd have to use jQuery, and Matt Bodily's answer. Using a form like this is really a more of an accepted way of doing things, since you're looking to retrieve dynamic information from the client on the server. It all depends on how you're using it, and which convention you want to follow.

Comment: string.empty should be string.Empty with a captital: E

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "my-form"}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("String")
}

<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('my-form').submit();>@p</a>
```

You can use `FormMethod.Post` or `FormMethod.Get`. The latter will append ?String= to the url.