# passing multiple parameter to another action using anchor tag not using html.actionlink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass 2 or 3 parameters to another action result via query string using anchor tag instead of `Html.ActionLink`, because am doing dynamically in C# adding anchor tag to particular element.

**here dt is table which contains the columnd are survey_id and vin .**

i am trying to replace particular column value as hyperlink and passing params to another action. please refer below code.

```
string surveyId ,vin;

foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
{
    // Url.Action(
    surveyId = dr["Survey_Id"].ToString();
    vin = dr["VIN"].ToString();
    //dr["Survey_Id"] = "@Html.ActionLink(" + surveyId.ToString() + ",'Index','SurveySummary', new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = 'Corporate' }), new { @class = 'NNAHyperlink' })".ToString();
    dr["VIN"] = "<a href='../corporate/surveysummary?vinid='"+vin+"class='HyperLink' style='text-decoration: underline;'>" + vin + "</a>";
}
```

corporate is controller and survey summary is one of the action result. i need to pass vin as well survey id dynamically to another action.

but i tried to pass vinid dynamically , it doesn't works correctly

it returns the URL like  **"http://xx.com/corporate/surveysummary?vinid="**

how can i change this ?

Answer (score 2):

I use url.action for this.  try

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { surveyId = dr["Survey_Id"].ToString(), vin = ...
```

Edit: 
regarding your last comment it is probably easiest to use the viewbag for this.  So in your controller:

```
ViewBag.SurveyId = dr['Survey_Id'].ToString();
ViewBag.Vin = vin;
```

and then on your view

```
<a href= '@Url.Action('Index', 'corporate/surveysummary', new { surveyId = ViewBag.SurveyId })'>@ViewBag.Vin</a>
```

Comment: whether this can be placed in C# ? because i need to do this in C# not view page.

Comment: whether it also be dynamic  ? since i need to do dynamic then how can i give url.action as string to href attribute in anchor tag

Comment: I have always found it easier to send the parameters to the view from the controller and build the url on the view. you mentioned dynamic.  do you need this link to be built based on fields on the view?

Comment: to build a dynamic url you need to use jquery.  Is this based on table values or a check button click to select an item?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662629/passing-html-textbox-value-as-a-parameter-to-controllers-method-in-asp-net-mvc/20662731#20662731 for the jquery

Comment: am asking how can i give this as string  "<a href= '@Url.Action('Index', 'corporate/surveysummary', new { surveyId = dr['Survey_Id'].ToString()>" + vin + "</a>"

Comment: that is what am meaning as dynamic. dont want jquery concept

Comment: thanks matt.i need to give anchor code as string. "<a href=''></a>".that what am asking how can i give as string with it contains the dynamic content as you posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43846/discussion-between-matt-bodily-and-sivarajini)