# passing model or multiple parameters to another action via anchor tag or any hyperlink concept

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have some data table that will be displayed like grid. Please refer below table like

```
Column1  Column2    Colum3
Siva     1200        200
Ram      2000        300
```

i want to make particular row value as hyperlink for example column2 all values will be hyperlink. i have implemented like below code

```
//Data table DT
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
 value= dr["Column2"].ToString();
     dr["Colum2"]="<a href= '@Url.Action('Index', 'Result', new { name= dr['column1'].ToString(),val= dr['column2'].ToString()})'>" + value+ "</a>"
}
```

i have modified column1 as hyperlink and passing two values **name and val to Result controller.**

but its not working properly since **i given anchor tag as string** so it takes href as **'@Url.Action('** up to this only.**(i.e skipped the remaining parts because of quotes end)**

so i need **how can i give anchor tag as string and giving dynamic values in href as like updated in above code.** (i.e need to pass two or more  dynamic values to result controller)

i want to implement this in C# only. i can't go to view and do some javascript code.

how can i do this ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing multiple parameter to another action using anchor tag not using html.actionlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763075/passing-multiple-parameter-to-another-action-using-anchor-tag-not-using-html-act)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create link like

```
//Data table DT
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper  = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
    var url =urlHelper.Action('Index', 'Result', new { name= dr['column1'].ToString(),val= dr['column2'].ToString()});

    value= dr["Column2"].ToString();
    dr["Colum2"]="<a href= '" + url +"'>" + value+ "</a>"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***This is how you need pass parameters to Controller:***

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionname", "Controllername", new { param1 = value,param2= value})"
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: i knew how to use url.action see my question clearly what am  asking exactly